# OnClick doesn't get real button id

Tags: android

I initialised a button with

> Button button1 = null;

in the beginning of my activity.
After the layout is set, I do

```
final   Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The onClick looks like that

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == button1) {System.out.println("asd");};
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

The print shows `"I/System.out(22758): android.widget.Button@**405632f0**"` and of course, the println("asd") doesn't show up.

I don't want to get the Button@****** code for every single button because working with the id of course is much easier.

Someone has in Idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Try if v.equals(button1) instead of ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == button1) {System.out.println("asd");};
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

use this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {System.out.println("asd");};
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

**WHY??**

because when you are comparing using '==' the it is comparing two objects wheter it is the same reference. that i checks whether both object refers to the same memory.

To solve this you can check their id which is easily comparable.

Comment: Thank you guys, all of the solution worked. I will mark all as answer. Silly me. And thanks for the advice that v.getId() is better, will use that in future. Have a nice day

Comment: check updated answer for details.. please acceept if any of our answer is helpful

Comment: sorry there was a time limit and I was afk for a few hours

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.button1` is actually an Integer in `R.java`, it's not a String or anything else that can be truncated to `button1`. Instead use:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
```

Also in Java you cannot use `==` to test equality on non-primitive objects, you *must* use `equals()`.  Read about the difference in [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661)

Comment: Thank you guys, all of the solution worked. I will mark all as answer. Silly me. And thanks for the advice that v.getId() is better, will use that in future. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

button1 is null. So you compare null and not null.
change this:

```
final   Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and it will work. But you better compare R.id.button1 and v.getId() numbers. Not views itself.

Comment: Thank you guys, all of the solution worked. I will mark all as answer. Silly me. And thanks for the advice that v.getId() is better, will use that in future. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

as @Leonidos said, change:

```
final   Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and, yes, you **can** compare references: if you see android sources there are two strategies: some people compare reverences like:

```
if (v == mSomeButton) {
```

and some use id like:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.some_button) {
```